# Атрибут contenteditable не работает в Google Chrome, если блок пустой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть таблица и некоторые её ячейки имеют атрибут contenteditable, чтобы текст в них можно было редактировать. В мозиле всё работает нормально, а в других браузерах (хром, яндекс, эдж) если ячейки уже содержат текст, то всё работает, а если текст стереть или его изначально нет, то написать новый невозможно. Почему так и как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А можно код посмотреть?

Comment: Возможно это из-за  того, что это свойство не везде поддерживается https://caniuse.com/?search=contenteditable

Comment: @DanilApsadikov почему это, оно везде [поддерживается с ранних версий](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrI9e.png). ([Ссылка на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable#browser_compatibility))

Comment: @all_possible думаю вам нужно через JS проверять есть ли текст, и если текста нет, тогда поставить пробел вместо пустой строки, чтобы таблицу можно было бы изменить.